# What does this error mean? PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation

Tags: php, drupal, error-handling

I´m pretty desperate here, I have this Drupal 7 production site and out of the blue, I get this error (at the logs) at whatever admin page I get into:
What does this mean?

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '25309582' for key 'PRIMARY': INSERT INTO {accesslog} (title, path, url, hostname, uid, sid, timer, timestamp) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5, :db_insert_placeholder_6, :db_insert_placeholder_7); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => Comienza a refacturarse el gas desde enero de 2012 sin los subsidios, comenzando por los Countries - Resolución 1993/2011 ENARGAS [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => node/4683 [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => 108.162.219.179 [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 0 [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => CD06pUUKdnaon6k1zaROEhXUPT9DkfVD7fW4UgyEHAw [:db_insert_placeholder_6] => 997 [:db_insert_placeholder_7] => 1364613253 ) in statistics_exit() (line 93 of /home/liga/public_html/modules/statistics/statistics.module).
```

I´ve deactivated statistics modules, and it is still there...

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: shouldn't an INSERT with duplicate key result in an UPDATE rather than an error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQLSTATE\[23000\]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1922-1' for key 'IDX\_STOCK\_PRODUCT'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10044062/sqlstate23000-integrity-constraint-violation-1062-duplicate-entry-1922-1-f)

Comment: Thanks for the link to the other question. As it was about Magento I thought that maybe it were about different things, but as Kingalione said, it´s a database issue...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your primary keys. You try to insert a dataset with a duplicate primary key but the key 25309582 is not given in the array.

Comment: Thank you! It seems resolved truncating the accesslog table. Thank you very, very much.